# Simulation of motion of charged particle around a spherical body in spherical polar coordinates. I am unable to get the animation right

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, simulation, numerical-methods, odeint

I am trying to plot and animate the motion of a charged particle in a planetary magnetic field by solving the equations of motion. I am able to get the 2D and 3D plots. But the 3D plot is giving only one of the 2D plots.

The solutions gave the values of r (radial distance), theta (latitude), phi (longitude), and their time derivatives (velocities) w.r.t time (here, 10e5 seconds).

Can someone help me with the animation/suggest ideas to go about it so that one can actually see the motion around in spherical (planet) object?

The code:

```
import NumPy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from math import sin, cos, pi
    from scipy.integrate import odeint
    
    scales = np.array([1e2, 0.1, 1, 1e-15, 10, 0.1])

    GM = 379312077e8    # m^3/s^2       
    β = 9.67e7  

    def odes(p, t):
        r,x,θ,y,ϕ,z = p*scales   # assigning each ODE to a vector element
        
        # constants
        R = 60268e3
        g_10 = 21141e-9
        Ω = 9.74e-3
        B_θ = (R/r)**3*g_10*sin(θ)
        B_r = 2*(R/r)**3*g_10*cos(θ)
        β = 9.67e7

   # defining the ODEs only Lorentz Force
        drdt = x
        dxdt = r*(y**2 +(z+Ω)**2*sin(θ)**2-β*z*sin(θ)*B_θ)
        dθdt = y
        dydt = (-2*x*y +r*(z+Ω)**2*sin(θ)*cos(θ)+β*r*z*sin(θ)*B_r)/r 
        dϕdt = z
        dzdt = (-2*(z+Ω)*(x*sin(θ)+r*y*cos(θ))+β*(x*B_θ-r*y*B_r))/(r*sin(θ))

        return np.array([drdt,dxdt,dθdt,dydt,dϕdt,dzdt])/scales

   # initial conditions
    r0 = 6.7e+07
    x0 = 0.0
    θ0 = 88.0
    y0 = 0.0
    ϕ0 = 0.0
    z0 = 0.022

   # time window
    t = np.arange(0,3600*24,360)
    p0 = np.array([r0,x0,θ0,y0,ϕ0,z0])
    p = odeint(odes,p0,t, atol=1e-8, rtol=1e-8)

    r,x,θ,y,ϕ,z = p.T*scales[:,None]

   # 2D plot the results
    fig,ax=plt.subplots(2,3,figsize=(8,4))
    plt.ylabel('parameters')
    for a,u in zip(ax.flatten(),[r,x,θ,y,ϕ,z]):
        a.plot(t,u); a.grid()

    plt.tight_layout(); plt.show()

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
 
   # 3D plots
    fig = plt.figure()
    omega=50
    x_line= r
    y_line =θ
    z_line =ϕ
    ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
    ax.plot3D(x_line,y_line,z_line, 'red')
    ax.view_init(120,120)
    plt.show()
```

2D plots of r, theta, phi, dr/dt, dtheta/dt, dphi/dt over time:

[image: 2D plots of r, theta, phi, dr/dt, dtheta/dt, dphi/dt over time]

3D plots of r, theta, and phi:

[image: 3D plots of r, theta, and phi]

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to convert the spherical coordinates to cartesian:

```py
# I don't have any clue about your differential equations.
# Maybe you need to convert the angles to radians. That's up to you do decide.
θ = np.radians(θ)
ϕ = np.radians(ϕ)
# spherical to cartesian
x_line= r * np.sin(θ) * np.cos(ϕ)
y_line = r * np.sin(θ) * np.sin(ϕ)
z_line = r * np.cos(θ)
```

Comment: Thank you. This would mean converting the spherical polar coordinates to cartesian coordinates. In plot can how to put a sphere or radius R in the middle an plot the variables (x, y z) around this sphere?